# What is the default value of a NULLABLE JSON field in Postgres / SQLAlchemy?

Tags: json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a PostgreSQL database with a JSON field. It was created / is interacted with via SQLAlchemy.

I am currently struggling to find where some JSON `null` values come from. So not the database `NULL` but the JSON value.

The column was created via:

```
sa.Column("fieldname", sqlalchemy_utils.types.json.JSONType(), nullable=True),
```

If this attribute is not explicitly set, what is the default value of it? Is it `null` (JSON) or `NULL` (DB)?

Comment: When I do a "raw" insert, directly via PgAdmin4, then it is NULL

Comment: JSON `null` exists only inside a JSON array or object. If you are leaving the column without either of these and it is `nullable` then the value will be the SQL `NULL`.

Comment: 'null' is  also a valid json data which is different from the NULL value in postgressql. Maybe your SQLAlchemy interface creates the 'null' :: json value by default instead of the NULL postgressql value ?